# changing const values at develop-time without recompiling everything

Tags: c++, file-io, settings

Right now I have a considerable amount of would-be magic numbers stored in constants. These get tweaked a lot in between each build. eg `const int numAPPLES = 25`

right now these are each defined at the top of each associated class header. But sometimes they need to be shared and I and up having to either:

1. Copy the definition; and risk conflicting values
2. include extra header (which is what I've done)

I previously had them all in an `options.h` which is great because I can see them all together but changing a number would obviously trigger a complete rebuild.

If it matters I am using VS 2010.

**What is the best way to allow changing these numbers? I am wondering how I could add a .txt file to my VS project and then extract the variables from there.**

the data types are (for now) only `char`, and `int`

I also don't want to have a whole library dependency just to access them. But a simple recommended class; or way to build own would be great.

thanks!

---

edit:
does this look good to you guys?: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/IniReader.aspx

Comment: The question title seems confusing. You do not seem to really want to change them at compile time, you want to change them post compile and pre run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need the constants at compile time, you really have to recompile when they change.

If you only need the values at runtime, you can declare them as

```
extern const int numAPPLES;
```

and put the actual values in a separate .cpp file. When you change a value, you just have to recompile that one file.

Comment: ... or you can even read them during the program startup, and not recompile anything.

Comment: @Suma could you elaborate on that a little? do you mean using an ini or something else?         Also, using an `extern` doesn't require includes? as far as I've read, this seems to be the case.

Comment: Yes, you can read them from a configuration file. It may be ini, it may be Yaml, Json, whatever you are able to parse easily. Boost.Program_options provides one nice and flexible solution.

Comment: Note that this will enable you to declare and use the constants only at runtime. A `extern` constant cannot be used as a compile time constant in any translation unit besides the one that actually defines the value.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a .ini file which is read at runtime to store all these constants? 
You can then read such files using `GetPrivateProfileInt`/`GetPrivateProfileString`. As fas as my experience goes it is a pretty common way to deal with your situation under Windows.

Here's an example given a simple Try.ini file:

```
..
[Section1]
Const1 = 1
..
```

And the code snipper:

```
CString FileName = _T("Try.ini");
int Value = GetPrivateProfileInt( "Section1", "Const1", DEFAULT_ERROR, FileName );
if( Value == DEFAULT_ERROR)
  return ERROR;
```

Cheers

Comment: would that be different/simpler that using a txt?....Off to google about this.. edit: searching for .ini yielded much better results that searching for "write to txt"!

Comment: Yes, overall is much easier than reading a file "from scratch", see my previous answer edited for an example.

Comment: I'll definitely remember this for when I build a UI and need to save user changes.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for edit: No, [it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/IniReader.aspx) does not look good. What are all those magic 255's scattered all over the code? It's C++ code, so what are char* strings doing there?

I guess it could be useful if it compiles as is and you're able to integrate it into your code right away. Then when you are comfortable with it, you can keep the interface and rewrite the methods for clarity and safety.

But I suggest you take a look at some libraries, and the first one that comes off the top of my head is [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/program_options.html).

Comment: thanks for confirming that, i thought it looked pretty awkward